# Rank Correlation Coefficient

Tags: code-golf, math, statistics

The usual [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) (in 2d) measures how well a set of points can be described by a line, and if yes, its sign tells us whether we have a positive or negative correlation. But this assumes that coordinates of the points can actually interpreted quantitatively for instance as measurements.

If you cannot do that but you can still *order* the coordinates, there is the *rank correlation coefficient*: It measures how well the points can be described by a *monotonic* function.

#### Challenge

Given a list of 2d points, determine their *rank correlation coefficient*.

#### Details

- You can assume the input to be positive integers (but you don't have to), or any other "sortable" values.
- The points can be taken as a list of points, or two lists for the x- and y-coordinates or a matrix or 2d array etc.
- The output must be a floating point or rational type, as it should represent a real number between 0 and 1.

#### Definitions

**Rank:** Given a list of numbers `X=[x(1),...,x(n)]` we can assign a positive number `rx(i)` called *rank* to each entry `x(i)`. We do so by sorting the list and assigning the index of `x(i)` in the sorted list `rx(i)`. If two or more `x(i)` have the same value, then we just use the arithmetic mean of all the corresponding indices as rank. Example:

```
          List: [21, 10, 10, 25, 3]
Indices sorted: [4, 2, 3, 5, 1]
```

The number `10` appears twice here. In the sorted list it would occupy the indices `2` and `3`. The arithmetic mean of those is `2.5` so the ranks are

```
         Ranks: [4, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 1]
```

**Rank Correlation Coefficient**: Let `[(x(1),y(1)),(x(2),y(2)),...,(x(n),y(n))]` be the given points where each `x(i)` and `y(i)` is a real number (wlog. you can assume it is an integer)
For each `i=1,...,n` we compute the *rank* `rx(i)` and `ry(i)` of `x(i)` and `y(i)` respectively.

Let `d(i) = rx(i)-ry(i)` be the *rank difference* and let `S` be the sum `S = d(1)^2 + d(2)^2 + ... + d(n)^2`. Then the *rank correlation coefficient* `rho` is given by

```
rho = 1 - 6 * S / (n * (n^2-1))
```

#### Example

```
x   y   rx              ry   d      d^2
21  15  4               5   -1      1
10  6   2&3 -> 2.5      2    0.5    0.25
10  7   2&3 -> 2.5      3   -0.5    0.25
25  11  5               4    1      1
3   5   1               1    0      0

    rho = 1 - 6 * (1+0.25+0.25+1)/(5*(5^2-1)) = 0.875
```

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) : "Only if all n ranks are _distinct integers_, it can be computed using the popular formula"

Comment: What do you want to say with that?

Comment: I say that the formula that you provided is for the special cases where  the ranks are integers according to wikipedia. However you used the formula for the ranks such as `2.5`.

Comment: Well that is if you're using integers in the first place. And even if you're doing so, you're still gonna get a good approximation. Many authors even use the formula of this challenge as a definition. Furthermore keep in mind that a *ranking* is unstable and does not necessarily have a such an impactful meaning as an usual correlation coefficient. But all this is irrelevant for this challenge.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 33 bytes

```
,it7#utb,&S]2XQw)]-Us6*1GntUq*/_Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/XyezxFy5tCRJRy041igisFwzVje02EzL0D2vJLRQSz8@8P//aCNDawVDAwg2MrVWMI7lijYE0mbWCuZAUaCsaSwA)

#### Explanation

```
,           % Do...twice
  it        %   Input a numeric vector. Duplicate
  7#u       %   Replace each element by a unique integer label (1, 2, ...)
  t         %   Duplicate
  b         %   Bubble up: moves original numeric vector to top
  ,         %   Do...twice
    &S      %     Sort and push the indices of the sorting
  ]         %   End
            %   The above do...twice loop gives the sorted indices (as
            %   explained in the challenge text) for the current input
  2XQ       %   Compute average for entries with the same integer label
  w         %   Swap: move vector of integer labels to top
  )         %   Index. This gives the rank vector for the current input
]           % End
-           % Subtract the two results. Gives d
Us          % Square each entry, sum of vector. S
6*          % Times 6. Gives 6*S
1G          % Push first input vector again
n           % Number of entries. Gives n
t           % Duplicate 
Uq          % Square, minus 1. Gives n^2-1
*           % Times. Gives n*(n^2-1)
/           % Divide. Gives 6*S/(n*(n^2-1))
_Q          % Negate, plus 1. Gives 1-6*S/(n*(n^2-1))
```

Comment: I've never seen something with such resemblance to keyboard mashing that actually does something before. +1

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```r
function(x,y)1-6*sum((rank(x)-rank(y))^2)/((n=sum(x|1))^3-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlZCoQwEAWv85500I5Ev7zKgAQCIrbgAhHm7nGBgoKqraShpNPiMa2GLBfVddV@LsA22oxM9/kif541YMM781@f0DpjSYjwKtq8@CAtJUKDdNKLqgSy3A)

[`rank`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rank.html) in R is the builtin that computes the desired rank; the rest is just the math to do the rest of the job.

*Thanks to [CriminallyVulgar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72784/criminallyvulgar) for saving 4 bytes*

As mentioned [in the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138305/rank-correlation-coefficient#comment339175_138305), the stated definition of rank correlation coefficient doesn't correspond precisely to the Spearman correlation coefficient, else a valid answer would be 26 bytes:

```r
function(x,y)cor(x,y,,"s")
```

Comment: Wee 4 byte tweak: (n^3-n) for the last bracket

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar thanks! my wedding was not too long after your comment so I didn't see it...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 141 bytes

```python
lambda X,Y,Q=lambda U,S=sorted:[S(U).index(y)+S(U).count(y)/2+.5for y in U]:1-6*sum((i[1]-i[0])**2for i in zip(Q(X),Q(Y)))/(len(X)**3-len(X))
```

This defines an anonymous function which takes input as two lists corresponding to the `x` and `y` values. Output is returned as a floating-point value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczLCoMwEIXhV8lyEsdLIrEg@BAigppmYaulAY3iBWpf3mpbmMX54GfGbXkONtyr5Lp3dX9ralJgiWnyR45ZMg/T0jaxyiCnnrFN@4KNOl/dh9Uuh3zhePIxTGQjxpJcx9yN2Lz2AEZx7RoVaMqYOAtzFm8zQgoFxRRKSqkPXWsPMha6v0X3cTLH6wqU4MiD84TEUCNRXGKEF@QcpT7CDw)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 89 bytes

```
(F[x_]:=Min@N@Mean@Position[Sort@x,#]&;1-6Tr[(F@#/@#-F@#2/@#2)^2]/((y=Length@#)(y^2-1)))&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYnRCoMgGEZfRRBCQWk6arAh/FddrRFsd2IjRi1hUygviujZnbCLwzl837cLo33NcVCRVHp5mrOqrYMb1H3noPGzDdY7ffdTgIVhk10ELx8@dB9NKsA5YJ4kkyVtpckJWdW1d@8wAqZkbSUXlNIsNpN1AcGgNykYEoc/smDouDO0iRQlQ6c0p7vYTfwB)  (in order to work on mathics, "Tr" is replaced with "Total")